# in what scenario the sum of two simplified fractions with LCD as denominator may be further simplified?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given $\frac{a}{A}$ and $\frac{b}{B}$ be two simplified fractions and $\operatorname{lcd}(A,B)$ be the Least Common Denominator of $A$ and $B$. 
Let $\frac{a}{A}+\frac{b}{B}=\frac{c}{\operatorname{lcd}(A,B)}$

Question:

in what scenario $\frac{c}{\operatorname{lcd}(A,B)}$ may be further simplified, or put another way, there may exist a common factor between $c$ and $\operatorname{lcd}(A,B)$

Comment: Hint: $1/3 + 1/6 = 1/2$.

Comment: I think you mean "lcm" rather than "lcd"; "lcd" is a liquid-crystal diode; "lcm" is the "least common multiple". : )

Comment: LCD can mean Least Common Denominator

Comment: @dxiv: thanks for the example. can there be a proof?

Comment: @techie11 Sorry, proof of what? It's not clear what is the statement that you mean to prove. The title asks `can sum ... be further simplified?` and the example I gave proves that the answer is `yes`.

Comment: @dxiv 5: I rephrased the problem. hope it clarifies. thanks

Comment: @techie11 The sum fraction simplifies iff $\gcd(aB+bA,AB) \gt \gcd(A,B)$ and I don't know that you'll find a much simpler condition.

Comment: @dxiv 5: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Counter example:

$$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{5}{12}$$

Comment: I think this is true in most cases. it is rare that such fraction can be further simplified. like the example @dxiv 5 gave.